# How to use Google Users API with Google App Engine and Android

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, oauth

Server is on Google App Engine, and the client is an Android mobile app.  I want to use the Users API to log users in from Android via a REST API on GAE.

In the Users API documentation it looks like the key (to construct a User object on the server) is the email.  But I'm told there's a way to get the User Object via and oauth token.  Meaning you'd call users.get_current_user() and the token would be used automatically to fetch that User Object.

Questions:

1 - Are there any examples of this process (code) available?
2 - Where does the Users API expect to find the oath token?  As a request parameter?  Is the token injested automatically at the time get_current_user() is called?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to do the same thing, only I am not using OAuth.  Instead I'm using google's authentication.  I am trying to get the User object by passing the ASID cookie with the request, but I always get null returned from getCurrentUser(). I have posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811730/login-to-appengine-from-android-client .  I use java on appengine though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [OAuth API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html#OAuth_and_App_Engine) docs:

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth

user = oauth.get_current_user()
```

With a valid OAuth request, this will return a db.User object just like users.get_current_user().

OAuth endpoint URLs for your app are detailed on the same page.

Comment: Thanks, that is mostly clear to me with one remaining question.  "Once authorized, the consumer calls the service provider to get an access token. The consumer includes this token with all requests to the application's web service endpoints." -- how is the token provided?  As a query string param?

Comment: The access token is included as part of the Authorization header. See the example @ http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth